# Form of custom distance function in scipy clustering

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

The documentation here - http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering.html#sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering.fit

States that I can use a callable distance function for clustering.

However I could not find the form of the distance function. Best guess `def dist(element1,element2)` pairwise distance function doesn't work. When it is called, it gets passed only one argument, which is a series of many arguments.

I couldn't find any documention detailing the function... does anyone know what type of function is expected?

(For my purpose, I want to classify some text of names based on a custom similarity function.)

Comment: Adding a `python` tag will probably greatly increase the number of people visiting this question.

Comment: Thanks... added. I would actually also want to know where I can get such info from. The document actually seems sparse in quite a few places like this... may be I am missing something?